# Is there any web video plugin that can record video?

Tags: video, video-recording

I know it's not good to ask for plugins on stackoverflow, but I'm really stuck there.

What I need is a video plugin that can play video (AVI or RTSP stream) in a web position, and it can record video by using API or something.

I have found VLC plugin, but it's official version do not support record.  Someone said recompiling its source code can make it support record; this may be my last choice.

I wonder is there any mature web video plugin which supports recording?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.

Flash Player has the unique ability to capture raw video from the webcam and encode it using Sorenson Spark or H.264, capture raw audio from the mic/sound card and encode it using Speex or NellyMoser and send this data to a media server (Red5, Wowza or Adobe Media Server) where the audio and video data are saved in a flv or f4v or mp4 file (depending on the media server and codecs used).

[Recording video using HTML5 currently only works on mobile browsers using HTML Media Capture](http://hdfvr.com/html5-video-recording).

A great plugin for your website that handles all of the above is the [HDFVR Webcam Video Recording Software](http://hdfvr.com/)